# How can I remove an eclipse plugin update address?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

Whenever I click on check for updates eclipse will tell me: 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/3 does not exist.
This is because it doesn't at some point I must have accidently added a 3 to the end.

However now it appears I cannot access updates for my plugins or manually install new ones as every time I click on help > check for updates eclipse will inform me the address above does not exist and refuse to open the software update window.

How do I remove this typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Window > Preferences. Then expand Install/Update > Available Software Sites. Highlight the site you don't want and click the Remove button.

Comment: Thanks. You wouldn't believe how long I've spent on something this simple.